# What is Exact Equivalent Conversion in C# Double Datatype And Sql Numeric

Tags: c#, sql, report, rdlc

Actually, I create an RDLC report, now I face a problem, my model's property's datatype is "double" but my SQL SP return Decimal because I use numeric (18,2), those datatypes create conflict when I want to bind SP to model.

```
var result = Database.SqlQuery<ReportVm>
        ("SP_InComeStatement @EntryDateFrom, @EntryDateTo, entryDateFromParam, entryDateToParam).ToList();
```

My ReportVm Property is:

```
public double? TotalAmount{get; set;}
```

and SP variable is:
ReceivableAmount numeric(18,2)
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

A `numeric(18, 2)` is a precise number, usable for holding financial data for example. `double` is a floating point number, and it is not meant to be precise.

I would advice to change the model. `decimal` will use the double amount of memory, but it will give your more precision than a `double`:

```
public decimal? TotalAmount{get; set;}
```

Comment: If I knew that, the amount around 0-12 digits, then why I use Decimal instead of double? can u suggest me, please

Comment: I think I mentioned that in my answer.